# Firebase login authentication fails with the correct credentials

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase authentication feature and I encountered a problem. I have two activities, SignUpActivity.java and SignInActivity.java. After I sign up for an account, I will be redirected to the sign in activity, where I  will key in my credentials. However, even with the correct credentials, I am still not able to log in. Below are the codes and screenshots

**Edit:** I am still unable to solve this problem.. Is there anyone willing to help me?

SignUpActivity.java

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Progress bar beings loading
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            createAccount(email, password);
        }
    });
}

public void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

SignInActivity.java

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            } else {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}
}
```

[image: Sign Up credentials]
[image: Sign up credentials send to firebase successfully]
[image: Sign in fails even with correct credentials]

Comment: have you put latest googleServices.json ?

Comment: Hi @MayurDabhi. I just downloaded the googleServices.json that the firebase website provided me when I created the project.

Comment: replace the latest .json file in app folder of android project. if problem still remain then first make sure which listener  of authentication is called if failed listener called then google related error code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's **sign in** tab and make sure you have email authentication enabled like in the picture below!

[image: firebase_authentication]

Comment: Hi, the email/password authentication has already been enabled before creating this  project. So, it is not the issue.